# Music reactive patterns with Java?

Tags: java, audio

My goal is a program that takes multiple sound files and creates a reactive visual pattern.
Like one of those Hardware visual synthesizers. [Example (YouTube)](https://youtu.be/SXUk_2qZLVA?t=445).

I have a bit of knowledge in Java but just basic stuff.
My 3 main questions are:

1. Is Java suitable for this kind of application?
2. What are the things I need to learn?
3. Are there any API's which can reduce the amount of work for me?

Answer (score 1):

I think Java should be a good language for this. Java gives you access to the raw audio byte data, and has strong graphic capabilities. Some sort of C language might provide slightly better performance but I don't know where to begin with even getting access to the audio data, as this seems to require dependencies rather than being built into the language.

I'm curious about how the visuals are formulated. As far as obtaining meaningful input from the sounds, I assume that it will employ real-time frequency analysis. When playing back audio files, one can use the class `SourceDataLine` to obtain access to the bytes as they are streamed to the native system.

I'd look for some sort of *FFT* or *Fast Fourier Analysis* library to take that input and create output signals that are mapped to amplitude activity in different frequency regions. How those signal become sources to a visual synthesizer is beyond what I know.

You might check out the [Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_(programming_language)) ecosystem. It's been around for quite a while. Looks like they now have spinoffs to JavaScript and Python and Android. So, I'm guessing your eventual choice of language depends on what systems you wish to run on and what you are most comfortable coding.